# How to show continue as gmail popup on right top?

Tags: php, laravel, google-api

I have implemented google login in my website. But i have seen some big sites are fetching my logged in gmail account in there website and show as **Continue as myname** in right side popup. Here is example below:-

[image]

Can anyone help me how to do this type of thing in my website or send me guide link so i can apply in my website. I am using laravel framework. I have also search on google but nothing found all tutorials showing google login.Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably because there's no code. Have you done anything yet? "_or send me guide link_" You'd be better off searching the web for any guide links, this is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
& [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions. Also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @kerbholz i have searched a lot but every tutorial related to google login. i have facing problem the stackoverflow is the best platform to resolve not to downvote some one answer

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1414410/how-to-disable-google-one-tap-sign-up-prompts

Answer (score 4):

The API for this type of stuff is called :

Googleyolo API

you can find the implentations on the internet. Refer to the links below.

https://github.com/zapier/google-yolo-inline/blob/master/index.html

https://medium.com/groww-engineering/all-about-googles-one-tap-sign-in-b8c1c93305d4

Comment: Consider explaining bits other than posting a link as an answer. The link might get broken in foreseen future.